# Send ubuntu stats on Databox

Tags: networking, server, stat

I would like to send stats about my Ubuntu machine on Databox (uptime, network traffic, free space...)
This will allow my colleagues to see the status of the machine.

Do you think that would be possible ? How ?

Or else do you have an alternative for them to see machine statistics from a website?

Comment: But how, that's the real question

Comment: You did not ask that ;-) Question: how difficult do you want this to get? We started out at some time by creating a script every hour where we put commands together and added the results to a file that got mailed.  Nowadays we have an apache server where we host our own webpage that has graphs and color coded notices with triggers to mail when thresholds are reached. We made all of those though w/o relying on pre-made software. Have a look at Monit for premade software https://mmonit.com/

Comment: I think the best solution would be a script which takes the informations and send it to Databox throught their API ( https://developers.databox.com/api/#send-your-data )
I agree with you, it's not what I asked at the beginning, I changed my post :)
I don't have the skills to do that script, that's why i'm asking here

Comment: That is something you will need to create yourself :-P You need a script on the server to gather all your info and a webpage on databox to show the results.

Comment: I know how to do everything on databox, but I need help with the script

Comment: AskUbuntu does not do coding ;-) But to get you started: Uptime in python: http://planzero.org/blog/2012/01/26/system_uptime_in_python,_a_better_way   free space: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260116/find-size-and-free-space-of-the-filesystem-containing-a-given-file  Network traffic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8958853/2920227

Comment: But unfortunally I need the script... I think I have to ask on another stackex ?

Comment: You can try but ... generally you need to create the script and when you run into problems you ask about that specific problem ;-) If you can code then python is a pretty easy language.